# Non-existent expectation and variance

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

I have a problem the answer for which is intuitively obvious but is more difficult than anticipated to actually show.

Claim: If X is a random variable such that the expectation of X does not exist, then the variance of X does not exist either.

This seems true on an intuitive level, as the variance is a measure taken relative to the mean. My issue is in showing that, for a discrete random variable X with E[X] and E[X^2] both infinity, V[X] does not exist. In this case, using the definition V[X] = E[X^2]-E[X]^2, I have a sum which diverges to infinity take (the square of) another sum which diverges to infinity, which I don't really know how to treat.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly use an alternate definition of variance, $V = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^2]$

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks for the response. But I'm not seeing how that makes it easier.

Comment: How are you going to define the variance? There is nothing to prove because is it is not possible to define variance when the expectation does not exist.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That makes sense. The problem asks to **prove** that the variance does not exist in the case I've outlined above, so I just wanted to check that there wasn't a proof by contradiction or something I hadn't seen.

Comment: Ben, sorry for delay, just saw this. @KaviRamaMurthy explained it in the next comment. The classic definition of variance is the one I posted above (avg deviation from the mean), and if the mean is undefined, variance as a concept does not make any sense.

Comment: @gt6989b No problem. I was thinking there might be a way to actually **show** that the variance in this case isn't a positive real number. But I'm now convinced that there's no need to. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Please see if the below is useful

\begin{align*}
\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^2 f_X(x) dx &= \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^0 x^2 f_X(x) dx + \int\limits_{x=0}^1 x^2 f_X(x) dx+\int\limits_{x=1}^\infty x^2 f_X(x) dx\\
&\geq \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^0 x^2 f_X(x) dx + \int\limits_{x=0}^1 0 f_X(x) dx+\int\limits_{x=1}^\infty x^2 f_X(x) dx\\
&\geq \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^0 x f_X(x) dx + \int\limits_{x=0}^1 0 f_X(x) dx+\int\limits_{x=1}^\infty x f_X(x) dx\\
&= \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x) dx +  \int\limits_{x=0}^1 (-x) f_X(x)  \\
&\geq \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x) dx -  \int\limits_{x=0}^1 1 f_X(x)  \\
&\geq \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x) dx -  \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)  \\
&= \left[\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x) dx\right]-1\\
&= \mathbb E [X]-1
\end{align*}
Therefore $\mathbb E [X^2] \geq \mathbb E [X]-1 = \infty$.

Let's call $\mathbb E[X] = \mu$. Then, $Var(X)=\mathbb E[(X-\mu)^2]$.
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{\mu\to\infty}Var [X] &=\lim\limits_{\mu\to\infty}\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu)^2 f_X(x) dx\\ 
&=\lim\limits_{\mu\to\infty}\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty [x^2 + \mu(\mu-2x)] f_X(x) dx\\
&=\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^2f_X(x) dx +\lim\limits_{\mu\to\infty} \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty\mu(\mu-2x) f_X(x) dx\\
&=\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^2f_X(x) dx +\lim\limits_{\mu\to\infty} \mu\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty(\mu-2x) f_X(x) dx\\
&\geq\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^2f_X(x) dx +\lim\limits_{\mu\to\infty} \mu\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) dx\\
&=\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^2f_X(x) dx +\lim\limits_{\mu\to\infty} \mu\cdot 1\\
&=\mathbb E [X^2] +\lim\limits_{\mu\to\infty} \mu\cdot 1\\
&=\infty
\end{align*}

Comment: This does not make sense. $EX$ not existing is not the same as $EX=\infty$ or $-\infty$. It may be impossible to assign even infinite values to $EX$; for example $EX^{+}$ and $EX^{-1}$ could both be infinity in which case you  cannto use $EX$ anywhere in your answer.

Comment: I thought the question was $E[X[$ does not exist *because* $EX = \infty$.In any case I see your point. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @RahulMadhavan Thanks for the reply.